# jQuery Keyup event is not firing for dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my code there is a div  with id="mix" generated dynamically with the jQuery load() method:

```
$('#mix').load('handlers/muscript.php');
```

muscript.php contains a few input element, which will be loaded into this div having id "mix" .

**the event keyup is not firing when the user enters their text.**

The code for creating the new input elements is:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('<input id="'+k+'" type="text" name="trans' + k + '"  />')
      .appendTo('#mix');
```

The code for capturing the user's values is:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    handler = $(this).val();
    name = $(this).attr('name');
```

This second code block work for the single element, but it is not fired for dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the event handler from

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
```

to

```
$('#mix').on('keyup','input' function() {
```